# What is blocking Google services on my PC?

Tags: anti-virus

My computer started acting strangely since last night.

1. Google related services: *.google.com (Gmail, Drive, Youtube) aren't opening. Even the Jquery script on this website (hosted on google) didn't load. Using browser tools in chrome, I could see that in none of the websites, these *.google.com scripts are loading.
2. All the searching engines (Google, DuckDuckgo, Bing) stopped working
3. Through Tor browser I am able to  access everything.

But I can open any other websites and download other stuff at my full net speed.

1. I checked the `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file. It is in its default state.
2. In Process Explorer `procexp` I can't notice anything fishy.
3. I ran `tracert`, `ping`, `nslookup` for all these: `mail.google.com`, `apis.google.com`, `r1---sn-cx5h-itqz.googlevideo.com`. They are all working perfectly well
4. In Glasswire firewall log I don't see anything unsual.
5. I scanned my system using Windows Defender, Kaspersky Virus Removal Took, Kaspersky Rootkit scanner. Nothing was found.

I don't know what else to do. Kindly help me solve this problem

Comment: Do you have another computer to test this with from the same Internet connection and public IP address to ensure it's not specific to the public IP these external sources see traffic originating? Since you say it starts to work with [Firefox] Tor (proxy) but. . . What web browsers have you tested from, Chrome, IE, FF, etc... something else to try? What are you using to open these external sources with exactly, web browsers and code language or what? And try from a different Internet connection and/or public IP address not related to Tor and compare results for troubleshooting.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT: I checked these on chrome & vivaldi. I should've checked on Firefox & Edge but didn't. Strangely, now everything is back to normal again. I have no clue what's happening.

Comment: ISP DNS issue perhaps? Ask them if they had any trouble and maybe that'll solve the mystery if they can confirm.